# JavaScript strict mode compatibility

Tags: javascript

While reading about [strict mode on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) I really was surprised to read the following near the end of the page, quote:

> Browsers don't reliably implement strict mode yet, so don't blindly
>   depend on it. Strict mode changes semantics. Relying on those changes
>   will cause mistakes and errors in browsers which don't implement
>   strict mode. Exercise caution in using strict mode, and back up
>   reliance on strict mode with feature tests that check whether relevant
>   parts of strict mode are implemented. Finally, make sure to test your
>   code in browsers that do and don't support strict mode. If you test
>   only in browsers that don't support strict mode, you're very likely to
>   have problems in browsers that do, and vice versa.

As far as I understand it, strict mode is a redused set of "nonstict" mode, thus I can't imagine situation where strict code can't run correctly in a nonstrict browser. So, the question is this statement really makes sense? Is the any situation where strict to "nonstrict" switch will make code invalid?

Comment: The only case I can think of is if you're relying on something that is only true in strict mode (such as this === undefined in a regular function call) or relying on something causing an error in strict mode that doesn't cause an error in non-strict mode.   Other than those odd things, yes you are correct that strict mode is more restrictive so normal code written in strict mode should work fine in non-strict mode.

Comment: @jfriend00 oh, indeed I missed the `this === undefined`. Though hard to imagine in actual usage it's certainly possible to break "nonstrict" code logic. You can probably convert your comment to answer.

Comment: Certain operations will throw an exception in strict mode, not in nonstrict mode.

Comment: @jfriend00 `this === window` in a regular function call, not `undefined` (unless there's something changing it higher up the call stack)

Comment: @Izkata *if you're relying on something that is only true in strict mode* - he meant in regular "strict mode" call.

Comment: @Izkata - In strict mode, `this === undefined` in a regular function call.  That is different than `this === window` in a regular function call in non-strict mode.  I'm just pointing outa difference between strict mode and non-strict mode.  Perhaps you didn't know that Javascript changes the value of `this` when you make a regular function call.

Answer (score 4):

Strict mode isn't just reduced functionality from "non-strict" mode. There's also some altered functionality. Say we'd like to write the following ES6 code:

```
function callOnObjectWithArgs(fn, obj, ...args) {
    fn.apply(obj, args);
}
```

But since browsers haven't implemented the rest operator (...) yet, we could do something like this in strict mode:

```
function callOnObjectWithArgs(fn, obj) {
    "use strict";
    var splice = Array.prototype.splice;
    splice.call(arguments, 0, 2); // Remove the first 2 elements (fn & obj)
    fn.apply(obj, arguments);
}

callOnObjectWithArgs(console.log, console, 1, 2, 3); // -> 1 2 3
```

However, this code would not work in "non-strict" mode.

```
// Using callOnObjectWithArgs without the "strict mode"; invocation
callOnObjectWithArgs(console.log, console, 1, 2, 3) // -> TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This is because by removing the first two elements from the `arguments` object, `fn` and `obj` will no longer point to the first two parameters passed to the function, but instead would then point to what was `arguments[2]` and `arguments[3]` from before the first two elements were removed (`1` and `2`). This is because in "non-strict" mode, named function parameters always point to the corresponding indices in the `arguments` object, whereas named parameters in strict mode are not bound to the `arguments` object in any way.

This is why you should always write code that is compatible with both strict and regular mode.